# Office365 portal surname/email change not updated in desktop Outlook/Teams

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-outlook-365

One of our team members have changed their surname.

Within the Azure/Office365 business portal, their email address and surname has been changed (with the old email address now being used as an alias and the new as the primary address) which has replicated through all the online services as expected.

However, in both Teams and Outlook desktop applications, the old name/email is still showing.

Checking all the settings shows the old data.  Is there any way to force an update/sync?

We've tried:

- Logging out/logging back in
- Switch accounts (only shows the new email address as already being selected)
- Rebooting
- Adding the new account in Outlook - it errors out saying its already added

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I'm afraid that there is no way to force an update/sync. Can other users normally see your new email address from their sides?
Have your information already been updated in the Global Address list?

And which email address you are using to log in to Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Teams right now? As I know, it usually takes 24 hours for the changes to take effect after modifying the account information. In addition, in order to avoid possible errors, it is suggested to remove the old account from your client and re-add this email account using the new email address to see if there is any difference.

So, from the perspective of the Outlook client, it is recommended that you create and use a new Outlook profile, reconfigure the account with the new email address, and observe whether the problem with the Outlook client is resolved.

Comment: Other users can see the new address in Outlook but not in Teams. The GAL is updated. Outlook shows the new address is being used but actually it isn't when settings are viewed. Is the recommendation to create a new profile documented anywhere? That was going to be our last course of action

Comment: How is everything going now? Creating a new configuration file may not be the easiest way, but it can completely reconfigure and resynchronize the account, avoiding many possible problems. If we have no other workaround, it is worth trying.